# detached entity passed to persist Kotlin

Tags: hibernate, jpa, kotlin

When I try to persist an entity, the following error occur

> org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to
>   persist: xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.**Invoice**

My model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "invoices")
class Invoice(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        var id: Long = -1,
        var date: Date,
        @Column(name = "user_id", unique = true)
        var userId: Long,
        @Column(name = "invoice_number")
        var invoiceNumber: String) : Serializable {

    constructor(date: Date, userId: Long, invoiceNumber: String) : this(-1, date, userId, invoiceNumber)
}
```

Invoice object is created as followed

```
val invoice = Invoice(Date(), 11111, "abc123")

invoiceDao.create(invoice)
```

In my generic dao I persist

```
fun create(entity: T): T {
    entityManager.persist(entity)

    return entity
}
```

*allopen* and *noarg* is included in my build.gradle

Comment: Do you have a default value for your id property? That may be the issue.

Comment: You've defined the id field as auto generated but assigned it a default value. When hibernate tries to persist it, it thinks that the object represents an underlying row in database because it already has an id. So, it considers it a detached object.

Comment: How can I do this in Kotlin? Set *null* to id?

Comment: I've not done Kotlin. I guess as long as you don't assign anything, it would take as null.

Comment: @Sashi setting `var id: Long? = null` works now. Please post an answer so I can accept yours :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've defined the id field as auto generated but assigned it a default value. When hibernate tries to persist it, it thinks that the object represents an underlying row in database because it already has an id. So, it considers it a detached object. 
The persist() method doesn't work on a detached object. 
You can set the default value of id to null to resolve this issue.